# Why int pointer gives me floating point number?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, casting

I have such code:

```
double x = 100.1;
double y;
int *p;

p = (int *) &x;
y = *p;

cout << "y value is: " << y << endl;
```

I understand that it's wrong and we get 4 bytes instead of our 8 bytes. I also know floating numbers have some tricky representation at memory (but don't know how), but this script gives me such output:

```
y value is: 1.71799e+09
```

As I understand it's also value with floating point. By my pointer is int and I also expect int result. Why it's not? What I should read to understand?

Comment: You *did* get an int result.  It just got formatted using a representation that's appropriate only for double.  Because that's what cout does when you pass a variable of type double.  And of course has a random value, anywhere between +/- 2 billion.

Comment: The integer was approximately 1717990000 (due to the tricky representation you noted). You then converted it to floating point and printed it.

Comment: GIGO. (For the kids out there, that's an ancient computing term that stands for Garbage In, Garbage Out)

Comment: Bits in memory (except in a few very early "tagged memory" systems) aren't "int" or "floating-point" or "char" or anything in particular.  Their meaning is provided by the variable name & type used to refer to the location in memory.  In your example above you printed the value while referring to it with a floating-point variable, so that is how it got printed.

Comment: @viakondratiuk what is the need of p=(int *)&x;. Is it typecasting to integer pointer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> By my pointer is int and I also expect int result. Why it's not?

Because `y` is a double, not an int. Now, if you mean to ask why doesn't `y` have an integral value, since it should be the result of the conversion of an int (which must* have an integral value) to double, take a look at the output of the following:

```
std::cout << "y value is: " << std::fixed << y << '\n';
```

The output you should see is:

```
y value is: 1717986918.000000
```

So, `y` *does* have an integral value, you simply printed it out using scientific notation. And if you wonder why `y` has this particular integral value, it's because that's the value `*p` had.

```
std::cout << "*p is: " << *p << '\n';

*p is: 1717986918
```

If you were to look at a memory dump of `x` with the value of `100.1`, you would see:

```
66 66 66 66 66 06 59 40
```

And when you access this as an int, you get `66 66 66 66`, which, converted to decimal, is 1717986918.

---

One other thing to note is that none of this is guaranteed by C++. In fact your program is not actually legal, because you're violating the aliasing rules when you access the double `x` through a pointer to int. Your program could be made legal and get the same results, but C++ doesn't specify the representation of floating point values, so the particular integral value could legally be different.

---

> What I should read to understand?

Here's an article that plays with the representation of floats: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/float.html

C++ doesn't specify how floats are represented, but most C++ implementations use IEEE-754, so you might also take a look at that specification. Here's the wikipedia page to start you on that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

To learn about C++'s aliasing rules you can find and read the spec. strict aliasing is covered in §3.10/10, IIRC. There are also plenty of questions and answers about aliasing here on SO.

Answer (score 4):

`1.71799e+09` is the floating point representation of the integer 1,717,99x,xxx.

Comment: While this may be true, it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Devolus: The answer to the question "I also expect int result. Why it's not?" is that **it is**.  `1.71799e+09` **is** an integer, represented as a `double`.  It has no fractional component.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

> By my pointer is int and I also expect int result. Why it's not?

Your pointer **is** `int *`, and you **are** getting an `int` result.

But that's not what you're displaying.  You're displaying `y` which is a `double`.

`1.71799e+09` is the double representation of the `int` you got.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
y = *p;
```

The variable *y* takes the *int* pointed to by *p*, and then converts it to a double.

Suppose `sizeof(double)` is 8 and `sizeof(int)` is 4

Doing `x = 100;` you put the `double` value 100 in *x* on 8 bytes. Then when you do `y = *p;` you would only use 4 of the 8 bytes, as an *int* value, then convert that number to a *double*.

The binary format of a *double* and of an *int* are different. E.g. 100 as *double* is not represented the same way as 100 *int* (let alone the size difference, e.g. 8 vs 4).

[See this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Answer (score 3):

```
double x = 100.1;
double y;
int *p;

p = (int *) &x;      
// Set a pointer of type integer to point at a floating point. Better C++ style
// would be p = reinterpret_cast<int *>(&x);
// which explains more clearly what you are doing - reinterpreting the pointer as
// a different type. 

y = *p;
// *p is an integer. So y is set to the value of *p, which is some crazy 
// integer value formed from the interpretation of a double as integer.

cout << "y value is: " << y << endl;
```

See comments in the code above. You are making a pointer point to data of a different type, then wondering why the binary digits transformed don't represent what it originally represented...

(Technically, this code is in violation of the rules about aliasing - basically, you are using the same piece of memory for two different purposes, and the compiler is not obliged to "do the right thing" in this case - I suspect it does something of what you can expect in this particular case - if what you expect is that you get an integer value represented by the four first bytes of a double, that is).

If you want `y` to actually contain the integer representation of the number in `x`, you want:

```
y = (int)x;
```

There is no sensible way we can use a pointer to do this conversion.

Comment: Using `reinterpret_cast` doesn't make the code any more correct; it's still an aliasing violation and this particular C-style cast happens to be defined in terms of `reinterpret_cast` anyway.

Comment: I said it would explain more clearly that it's a reinterpretation of the pointer - which I think it is. If you think that a novice understands (int *) just as clearly, then feel free to think so.

Comment: My complaint is that you said "Correct C++ would be ...", but it's not any more correct.

Comment: Ok, I've edited - I already added a section on "it's not good code".

Answer (score 0):

You're triggering undefined behavoir when you run the following line:

```
p = (int *) &x;
```

Once you've triggered undefined behavoir the rest of your question is fairly pointless as reasoning about undefined behavoir doesn't make sense (although looking at the rest of your question, it may be that this bit of undefined behavoir doesn't affect what you're really asking. I'm not sure though.)

Comment: you would have added it in a comment in this case

Comment: Just out of my personal curiosity, how is casting a int pointer to a float pointer an undefined behavior ? De-referencing such a pointer may be implementation dependent, but casting ? What part of the standard ?

Answer (score -1):

Read C++ pointers and data types documentation

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

Comment: If you downvote, you should leave a comment. Question was "What I should read to understand?"